# How do you turn off the message indicator in Hangouts?

Tags: google-hangouts

I don't want people to know when I saw their texts. Is there a way to turn the message indicator off?

Answer (score 1):

From [google's site:](https://support.google.com/chat/answer/162730?hl=en)

"Hangouts:

When chatting with someone who is using Hangouts, please keep in mind that you can't appear invisible on Hangouts.

When you set your Google Chat status to invisible, Hangouts users will see your profile picture without a green dot in their contact list, meaning that you may be idle or unavailable on your computer.

If you are signed in to Hangouts, you won’t be able to set your status to invisible."